# echo server with netcat or socat

Tags: netcat, socat, echoserver

I want a UDP echo server to get packets, and reply exactly what it has received. How can I simply do this using `netcat` or `socat`? It should stay alive forever and handle packets coming from several hosts.

Comment: Please don't make this thing Internet-accessible. Since it's UDP-based it can be used to send a packet stream to arbitrary destinations using source-forged packets.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Another netcat-like tool is the nmap version, `ncat`, that has lots of built in goodies to simplify things like this. This would work:

```
ncat -e /bin/cat -k -u -l 1235
```

-e means it executes /bin/cat (to echo back what you type)
-k means keep-alive, that it keeps listening after each connection
-u means udp
-l 1235 means that it listens on port 1235

Answer (score 17):

I used `socat -v PIPE udp-recvfrom:5553,fork` to run the server and `socat - udp:localhost:5553` for clients.
[This](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html#ADDRESS_TYPES) was a great help!

Comment: An alternative, coming from http://stackoverflow.com/a/35857095/222529 is `socat TCP4-LISTEN:2000,fork EXEC:cat`

Answer (score 12):

You can also use socat (rather than using netcat) as echo server and netcat as client.

Socat echo server (listens on TCP port 1234):

```
socat -v tcp-l:1234,fork exec:'/bin/cat'
```

Netcat client (connects to serverip on TCP port 1234):

```
nc serverip 1234
```

Answer (score 3):

**`netcat` solution pre-installed in Ubunutu**

The `netcat` pre-installed in Ubuntu 16.04 comes from `netcat-openbsd`, and has no `-c` option, but the manual gives a solution:

```
sudo mknod -m 777 fifo p
cat fifo | netcat -l -k localhost 8000 > fifo
```

Then client example:

```
echo abc | netcat localhost 8000
```

TODO: how to modify the input string value? The following does not return any reply:

```
cat fifo | tr 'a' 'b' | netcat -l -k localhost 8000 > fifo
```

The remote shell example however works:

```
cat fifo | /bin/sh -i 2>&1 | netcat -l -k localhost 8000 > fifo
```

I don't know how to deal with concurrent requests simply however.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a C program that [forks](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) `nc -u -l -p 4321` and then uses [dup(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup) to connect:

- nc stdin with the parent's stdout
- nc stdout with the parent's stdin

Then in an endless loop the parent reads from stdin and writes in stdout whatever the parent reads.

Comment: I can use `socat -v PIPE UDP-LISTEN:5555,fork`, but the second connection gets refused. By the way, it works fine with TCP-LISTEN.
I am avoiding to code, otherwise I could write it all in C.

Comment: You have to wrap the whole thing in an endless loop: while true; do socat stuff; done

Comment: You may also get some inspiration using [this tutorial](http://zarb.org/~gc/html/udp-in-ssh-tunneling.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on Windows and use a unix like environment like cygwin, netcat migth not provide the -e parameter. This worked just fine for me.

http://bansky.net/echotool/